# In Python, how to convert stacked unicode characters to image, like in case of 70,000,000,000 roman numeral?

Tags: text, unicode, python-imaging-library

I have created an integer to roman numeral conversion script which generates the following text given an input of 70000000000:

`L\u0305\u0305\u0305X\u0305\u0305\u0305X\u0305\u0305\u0305`

or so you can read it more easily:

`L^^^X^^^X^^^` where ^ = \u0305

Depending on the python shell in which you paste this string, you may or may not be able to see the three joined overlines.

Here is an image of what it should look like: [image]

I want to be able to produce an image like in the above example, given strings in the format described, potentially up to ten or more stacked overlines if possible, e.g. [image]

I have tried a few things with pillow but I haven't successfully been able to produce more than one overline on top of the other.

Comment: I'm not sure any font layouting system formats multiple U+0305 characters in the way you intend it to. It seems that chrome for example renders multiple ones either identical to a single one or just by having a slightly bolder overline (depending on the font, it seems). Compare L̅X̅X̅ (one overline each) with L̅̅̅̅X̅̅̅̅X̅̅̅̅  (4 overlines each).

Comment: Yes, @JoachimSauer, this is the essence of the problem. Text doesn't really work, so I want to produce an image instead. Might have to produce something custom which counts the number of overline characters and stacks them. They must have figured it out for the code behind this widget - https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/gallery/view.jsp?id=48c27d2ebfb0ff2417cb131015bc969f

Comment: I'd use something linke matplotlib (or any other thing that can render TeX-like math statements) to render `\overline{\overline{\overline{LXX}}}`, See [this question, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168292/render-latex-text-with-python).

Comment: In a vanilla ubuntu terminal, just copying and pasting text, e.g. 'L\u0305\u0305\u0305X\u0305\u0305\u0305X\u0305\u0305\u0305' into a python shell, shows the overlines stacked (up until a point, about three or so lines)

Comment: It depends on the font, so check a good font, which display the lines, and use pillow or other program, where you write the text in a image and you save the image. Note: in this case user will lose many functionalities (e.g. copy text, change size, ...)

Comment: interesting approach. Thanks. WIll look into tex.